# jQuery - Issue creating background-image from src

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to create a div with background-image: url() from an img tags src which is kind of working but the problem is that it clones the very first image and then uses this for the rest of the images as you can see in the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/tRmVT/

```
$('.panel .panel-slider').append('<div class="backbg"></div>');

var img = new Image();

function imgLoaded() {
    $('.panel .panel-slider .backbg').css("background-image", "url(" + img.src + ")");
}

img.onload = imgLoaded;
img.src = $('.panel .panel-slider .bg-fix').attr('src');
if (img.complete || img.readystate === 4) {
    imgLoaded();
}

// $('.panel-slider .bg-fix').remove();
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better solution is not hide the existing img elements than to create new image elements like

```
.panel .bg-fix {
    display: none;
}
```

then

```
//create the target elements
$('.panel .panel-slider').append('<div class="backbg"></div>');

//register load event handlers for the element
$('.panel .panel-slider .bg-fix').load(function () {
    //set the background image
    $(this).next().css("background-image", "url(" + this.src + ")");
    //remove the img element
    $(this).remove()
}).filter(function () {
    //if the image is already loaded then filter them
    return this.complete || this.readystate === 4
}).trigger('load'); //trigger load event manually for already loaded images
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nhLh3/)

---

Your solution: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/77F3Q/)